# Using IP geolocation with rails 3

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, html, geolocation

I'm trying to make part of my homepage dynamic where it will get the location object that is closest to your physical location.

I currently have a Location model with several fields including longitude and latitude.  I would like to return the location model object that is closest to the longitude and latitude of the reader's ip address.

I have looked at the geo-kit gem, but it doesn't have Rails 3 support.  I've also looked at the HTML5 geolocation, but it seems to only be client side (i.e. I get the lat and long of the user, but the page is already displayed).  I'm assuming I could use ajax, but I'm not really familiar with it and there might be a less resource intensive way.

What is the best way to approach this?

My current code using the HTML5 geo-location is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayLocation(loc) {
  var locDiv = document.getElementById("locationDiv");
  locDiv.innerHTML = "lat: " + loc.coords.latitude + ", lon:" + loc.coords.longitude;
}
function initialize(){
    var homeLocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
}
</script>
<section class ="round">
  <div id="locationDiv"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I use geokit-rails just fine in my Rails 3 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this gem a try: https://github.com/chrisyour/geo_location